# post action of jenkinsFile Stage get previous stage status instead of the current one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I'm having the following issue:
I have 2 stages on my pipeline and on stage 1 I got failure (expected) then the stage 2 is called (expected) and do what it needs to do and return success.
However on my post step of the stage 2 instead of it goes to success it goes to failure.
Does anyone knows how to bypass this?

```
stage('stage 1') {
    step {
        //failure
    }
}
stage('stage 2') {
    step {
        //success
    }
    post {
        success {
            echo 'I succeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up in this issue, and I suspect you were doing something like what I was doing (trying to catch an error in a `build` step):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    build 'job-which-fail'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
            steps { 
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'success stage 2'
                }
                failure {
                    echo 'failure stage 2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work and trigger the behavior that you described. However, this is intended, according to [this comment](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49073?focusedCommentId=390234&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-390234). The proper way to achieve such thing is by using `build` with `propagate: false`. I ended up with:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    script {
                        def myBuild = build(job: 'job-which-fail', propagate: false)
                        def myResult = "${myBuild.getResult()}"
                        if (myResult != 'SUCCESS') {
                            error "Build failed with result ${myResult}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
            steps { 
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'success stage 2'
                }
                failure {
                    echo 'failure stage 2'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below scenarios and answers:
If you get a failure on stage 1 then stage 2 will not be executed:
**Test 1**: Fail stage 1 and check the output

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages{
        
        stage('stage 1') {
              steps {
          echo "Hello stage 1"
           // deliberately failing stage 1
           bat "set 1"
          
         }
         post {
        success {
            echo 'I succeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
         }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
              steps {
          echo "stage 2"
          }
           post {
        success {
            echo 'I succeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
         }     
    }   
}
```

**Output** : Stage 2 is not executed/skipped due to failure in stage 1
[image]

**Test 2**: Pass stage 1 , Fail stage 2 and check the output.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages{
        
        stage('stage 1') {
              steps {
          echo "Hello stage 1"          
         }
         post {
        success {
            echo 'I succeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
         }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
              steps {
          // deliberately failing stage 2
         bat "set 1"
          }
           post {
        success {
            echo 'I succeeded!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
        }
        changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
        }
    }
         }       
        
    }
}
```

**Output** : stage 1 is passed and stage 2 is failed

[image]

So considering the above examples, it is clear that stage 2 will not be executed 
if stage 1 is failed. Please see the snippet as test code as reference example. 
If you want stage 2 to execute even if stage 1 fails then you should do `returnStatus` as `true` as shown below:
`bat label: 'set variable..', returnStatus: true, script: "set 1"`
By this way both stages will be succeedded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I describe is what I am facing.
Maybe I'm missing some information, the step that fails is using publishIssues, that came from one plugin https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/
In any case, I was able to find a workaround that is to not use the post action anymore.